# "bash: ./main: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error" using wsl2:Ubuntu on windows 11 Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

printf("Hello World");

return 0;

}
```

I build by:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c main.c -o main
```

`uname -m` gives "x86_64".

After compiling `file main` gives:

```
main: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

`strace ./main` gives:

```
execve("./main", ["./main"], 0x7ffc779cf7c0 /* 33 vars */) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
strace: exec: Permission denied
+++ exited with 1 +++"
```

Comment: Did you compile and link the source code? If so, by what command? Please [edit] your question when you add this important information. -- Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, this is not a forum.

Comment: used "gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -c main.c -o main" then ./main

Comment: What bash is this? The bash of the WSL or the bash of Windows?

Comment: its within the visual studio code while running wsl

Comment: This does not answer my question... ;-) For example, the bash of my Windows installation of Git is able to run `uname -m`, which prints "x86_64". Try `uname -a`.

Comment: returns "Linux DESKTOP-TR9B97O 5.15.57.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Jul 27 02:20:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `file main` once the program is compiled. Then install `strace` (`sudo apt install strace`) and take a look at the output of `strace ./main` - paste that into your question too, it could give more info on why your program is not working.

Comment: `-c` produces an object module to be linked later, not an executable. Remove it.

Comment: For the future: if you see `file` say "ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable" then it's not an executable program. For those, you would see "ELF 64-bit LSB executable" or "ELF 64-bit LSB shared object" depending on the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did only compile, but not link the program. Unlinked object files cannot be executed.

Change your build command to:

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic main.c -o main
```

Note the missing `-c`.